# How show more than one item per page with ant design (NG-Zorro) carousel?

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, antd, ng-zorro-antd

everyone,

How to show more than one item per page with ant design (NG-Zorro) carousel.
https://ng.ant.design/components/carousel/en

I want to show something like this - Multiple Items

https://ng.ant.design/components/carousel/en

Comment: You have posted both links as same.

Comment: any own attempt?

Comment: In react you have `slidesToShow` for ant Carousel , but this is only because ant Carousel exends the react-slick element . But in angular this is not the case. I checked their repository (here: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/tree/master/components/carousel) and nothing like this is included in their documentation or code. This is because, on angular, is not extending some component but is rather created with basic html elements.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show more than one item per page you can simply set **slidesToShow** property to the desired number.

```
  <Carousel slidesToShow={3}>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </Carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meybe you In the file css you have to remove     line-height: :

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer].